# SQLAlchemy error after upgrading to python 3.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and I wanted to upgrade python from 3.10 to 3.11. However, now I'm experiencing problem with flask when trying to run my project.

This is my pipfile:

```
[scripts]
start = "python app.py -h 0.0.0.0"
test = "coverage run --source . --omit app.py -m pytest -vv -s"

[packages]
flask = "*"
flask-sqlalchemy = "==2.5.1"
sqlalchemy = "<2"
flask-cors = "*"
marshmallow = "*"
flask-migrate = "==3.1.0"
psycopg2-binary = "*"
flask-jwt-extended = "*"
requests = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
gevent = "*"
srt = "*"
sentry-sdk = {extras = ["flask", "sqlalchemy"], version="*"}
beautifulsoup4 = "*"
lxml = "*"

[dev-packages]
black = "*"
coverage = "*"
flake8 = "*"
flake8-blind-except = "*"
flake8-comprehensions = "*"
flake8-docstrings = "*"
flake8-pep3101 = "*"
flake8-print = "*"
flake8-pytest ="*"
flake8-isort ="*"
pytest = "*"
smtpdfix = "*"
pylint = "*"
pyenchant = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.11"
```

And this is the error that appears after I succesfully sync the dependencies and run `pipenv run flask db upgrade`:

```
Usage: flask db upgrade [OPTIONS] [REVISION]
Try 'flask db upgrade --help' for help.

Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-75ZVCSlg/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 219, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/user/project/backend/app.py", line 4, in <module>
    from project import create_app
  File "/home/user/project/backend/project/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-75ZVCSlg/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from flask import _app_ctx_stack, abort, current_app, request
ImportError: cannot import name '_app_ctx_stack' from 'flask' (/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-75ZVCSlg/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/__init__.py)
```

I'm not sure which version of sqlalchemy is compatible with python version 3.11